# Solution to algebraic equations over $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}[x]$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, power-series, automorphic-forms

$t^n=a$, we get one solution to the equation:
$$t=e^{\frac{1}{n}\int^a_1 \frac{1}{x}}$$, generalizing this result by replacing  the exponential with an elliptic modular function and the integral with hyperelliptic integrals, we can get a solution to an algebraic equation  $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_nx^n=0$ with degree above 5 by formulation of  modular function and hyperelliptic integral(both formulated by Siegel Theta functions):
$$x=\frac{\theta\left(
  \begin{array}{cccccc}
    \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 &\cdots & 0  \\
  \end{array}
\right)(\Omega)^4\theta\left(
  \begin{array}{cccccc}
    \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \cdots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 &\cdots & 0  \\
  \end{array}
\right)(\Omega)^4}{2\theta\left(
  \begin{array}{cccccc}
    \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 &\cdots & 0  \\
  \end{array}
\right)(\Omega)^4\theta\left(
  \begin{array}{cccccc}
    \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \cdots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 &\cdots & 0  \\
  \end{array}
\right)(\Omega)^4}+\frac{\theta\left(
  \begin{array}{cccccc}
    0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 &\cdots & 0  \\
  \end{array}
\right)(\Omega)^4\theta\left(
  \begin{array}{cccccc}
    0 & \frac{1}{2} & \cdots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 &\cdots & 0  \\
  \end{array}
\right)(\Omega)^4}{2\theta\left(
  \begin{array}{cccccc}
    \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 &\cdots & 0  \\
  \end{array}
\right)(\Omega)^4\theta\left(
  \begin{array}{cccccc}
    \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \cdots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 &\cdots & 0  \\
  \end{array}
\right)(\Omega)^4}-\frac{\theta\left(
  \begin{array}{cccccc}
    0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
    \frac{1}{2} & 0 &\cdots & 0  \\
  \end{array}
\right)(\Omega)^4\theta\left(
  \begin{array}{cccccc}
    0 & \frac{1}{2} & \cdots & 0 \\
    \frac{1}{2} & 0 &\cdots & 0  \\
  \end{array}
\right)(\Omega)^4}{2\theta\left(
  \begin{array}{cccccc}
    \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 &\cdots & 0  \\
  \end{array}
\right)(\Omega)^4\theta\left(
  \begin{array}{cccccc}
    \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \cdots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 &\cdots & 0  \\
  \end{array}
\right)(\Omega)^4}$$

or

$$x=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\theta\left(
  \begin{array}{cccccc}
    0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 &\cdots & 0  \\
  \end{array}
\right)(\Omega)^4\theta\left(
  \begin{array}{cccccc}
    0 & \frac{1}{2} & \cdots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 &\cdots & 0  \\
  \end{array}
\right)(\Omega)^4}{2\theta\left(
  \begin{array}{cccccc}
    \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 &\cdots & 0  \\
  \end{array}
\right)(\Omega)^4\theta\left(
  \begin{array}{cccccc}
    \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \cdots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 &\cdots & 0  \\
  \end{array}
\right)(\Omega)^4}-\frac{\theta\left(
  \begin{array}{cccccc}
    0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
    \frac{1}{2} & 0 &\cdots & 0  \\
  \end{array}
\right)(\Omega)^4\theta\left(
  \begin{array}{cccccc}
    0 & \frac{1}{2} & \cdots & 0 \\
    \frac{1}{2} & 0 &\cdots & 0  \\
  \end{array}
\right)(\Omega)^4}{2\theta\left(
  \begin{array}{cccccc}
    \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 &\cdots & 0  \\
  \end{array}
\right)(\Omega)^4\theta\left(
  \begin{array}{cccccc}
    \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \cdots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 &\cdots & 0  \\
  \end{array}
\right)(\Omega)^4}$$
where $\Omega$ is the period matrix of the hyperelliptic curve $\mathbb{C}$, 
please see [David Mumford Tate lecture on Theta $\textrm{II}$ Jacobian page 266](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-0-8176-4578-6_18) for more detail.

Now let us extend this result to algebraic equation with coefficients of $p_i(x) \in Q[x]$ where $Q[x]$ is a ring.

$$p_0(x) + p_1(x) \cdot y + p_2(x)\cdot y^2 + \cdots + p_n(x)\cdot y^n $$
is an algebraic polynomial where $p_i(x)$ are the polynomials  with rational coefficients.
When $$p_0(x) + p_1(x) \cdot y + p_2(x)\cdot y^2 + \cdots + p_n(x)\cdot y^n =0$$, we have solution to the equation in which $y$ is formulated by modular function and hyperelliptic integrals with $x$ as variable, like $y= \phi(x)$, in another word, $$p_0(x) + p_1(x) \cdot \phi(x) + p_2(x)\cdot \phi(x)^2 + \cdots + p_n(x)\cdot \phi(x)^n =0$$

My question is when $y$ is expanded as power series (Taylor expansion) in $x$,as $$y=\sum_0^{\infty }b_i x^i$$, or $$\phi(x) = \sum_0^{\infty }b_i x^i$$, under what condition ( formulated by  modular function and hyperelliptic integrals ) can we have $b_i\in \mathbb{N}\bigcup 0$ ?

Comment: Do you understand that in order to even *begin* to understand what the Tata Lectures on Theta talk about, leave alone what's going on on page 266 of the volume II of that book, has *must* already know a whole lot of very, very advanced stuff **before** that? Meaning: your question is a Research Level one, more fit for Overflow than for this site. It also looks like a question that requires lots of background for anyone to get interested in it, so you'll probably need to write a lot more than what you did to explain yourself.

Comment: @DonAntonio. I don't know, I just think it is a hard question, thank you for your comment.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290251/solution-to-algebraic-equations-over-mathbbc-and-mathbbcx